# How to solve the following 4th order Ordinary Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, greens-function

How to solve the following equation by Green's function Method?

$$x^{(4)}_1(t)+(b_1+b_3)x''_1(t)+(b_1b_3-b_4b_2)x_1(t)={g}''_1(t)+b_3g_1(t)+b_2g_2(t)$$
with initial conditions:
$$x_1(0)=m_1$$
$$x_1'(0)=m_2$$
$$x_2(0)=m_3$$
$$x_2'(0)=m_4$$
where $b_j,m_j$ are constant for $i=1,2,3,4$

and $x_2=(x_1''+b_1\,x_1-g_1)/b_2$

In fact, I seek the solutions $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ which are depended on $g_1(t)$ and $g_2(t)$.

Comment: Are you sure about the minus sign in the zeroth order term?
\begin{align}
x_1''+b_1x_1&=g_1+b_2x_2\\
x_2''+b_3x_2&=g_2+b_4x_1
\end{align}
can be combined to the scalar equation
\begin{align}
b_2x_2''+b_3b_2x_2&=b_2g_2+b_2b_4x_1
\\
(x_1''+b_1x_1-g_1)''+b_3(x_1''+b_1x_1-g_1)&=b_2g_2+b_2b_4x_1
\\
x_1^{(4)}+(b_1+b_3)x_1''+(b_1b_3-b_2b_4)x_1&=g_1''+b_3g_1+b_2g_2
\end{align}
And why would you transform the second order system into a 4th order scalar equation?

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your interest. Yes, your calculations are right. In fact, I want to learn another method except from Matrix Differential Equation for solving the ode system. I guess that the system can be solved by Green's function method by transforming to 4th order Ode or directly. But I can't solve.